# Unable to connect back to Bluemix HLF after deploying bna to local HLF

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I created a separate connection.json file in its own directory for Bluemix and deployed my business network file successfully to Bluemix HLF and all the transactions worked fine from CLI and Loopback APIs.  Then I deployed the same network file (bna) to a local Docker HLF and everything worked too.  But now I am unable to issue any CLI commands to the Bluemix HLF - I keep getting a message:  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined".  I think it because the user and enroll secrets are different for the two connections.  The .composer-credentials directory has a file for member.WebAppAdmin (which corresponds to the local Docker HLF) but the user for the Bluemix HLF is admin and I remember seeing a member.admin file in the .composer-credentials directory earlier but now it is not there.

If the missing member.admin credential file is indeed the source of the problem, how does the proper .composer-credentials file get created when connecting to Bluemix HLF?  I am using CLI interface to deploy/update bna file to the HLF.  I tried both a deploy and an update command but keep getting the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined" error.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your connection profiles to use different `~/.composer-credentials/` folders. You should use a different folder for each Fabric you want to connect to, otherwise the ECerts are going to get overwritten or intermingled.

E.g. a sample connection profile looks like this:

`{
    "type": "hlf",
    "membershipServicesURL": "grpc://localhost:7054",
    "peerURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
    "eventHubURL": "grpc://localhost:7053",
    "keyValStore": "/Users/dselman/.composer-credentials",
    "deployWaitTime": "300",
    "invokeWaitTime": "100",
    "networks": {
        "digitalproperty-network": "cc2e7c63ebd68cc40425ca3b885c878183d3a3aa796f71154bc07955abd7e7d9",
        "vehicle-lifecycle-network": "ef7909bde9371c69ae9d6a2b3b7b74e532b3613b0eca1030607e46561e78e603"
    }`

You can change the path for the `keyValStore` to ensure the certs for different connection profiles are in different locations on disk.